# How to download all Apex classes from Prod using VS code

Tags: apex, vs-code

Now that Force.com IDE plugin for eclipse is unsupportive, is there any way to connect to Prod org using VS code and download all Apex classes. I can see all extensions for SFDX but I do not know how to connect it for traditional Production Org.
Please advise.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/development-models have you checked here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a connection to production org, follow below steps:-

Open command palette, search for **sfdx: Authorize an Org** and select it

[image]

Now, You will get few options to authorise. You can select Production Org to authorise to a production org:-

[image]

Then, VS Code will ask you for an alias name and once you press enter, it will open a browser window to authorise in your production org.

**How to retrieve all the apex class from Production?**

In your package.xml file, Copy below code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

and right click on the package.xml file and select sfdx: retrieve source in Manifest from org

[image]

Read more here:-

1. https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/02/21/setup-your-developer-environment-for-lightning-web-comp/
2. https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/09/09/xml-package-to-retrieve-metadata-from-org/

Answer (score 3):

We can also use these commands from the terminal:

Retrieve All Apex classes

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass`

Deploy All Apex classes (Never do, a very bad habit)

`sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexClass`