# SFDX without a project

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I'm writing an Apex class in my dev org. I want to use SFDX tools to connect to this dev org, write code in vscode editor and push it to dev org.

It seems the SFDX tools only work with a sfdx project. In my case, I just want to work on one apex class, don't want to pull all other unmanaged classes or metadata locally. Is this possible?

My current flow is to update the apex class locally and then copy and paste the code in Salesforce org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vscode you need  not retrieve all the metadata.

First once vscode setup is done you need to create a project with manifest and authorize the org from which you want to retrieve the apex class or deploy it.

Now open the package.xml from  under manifest and remove all the other components and add just the apex class and you can retrieve that particular class only.

The package.xml will look as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
    <members>CustomApexClassName</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

After making required changes you can deploy the same.

For vscode setup you can check below resources

[resource1](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/02/21/setup-your-developer-environment-for-lightning-web-comp/)
[resource2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292281/how-to-download-all-apex-classes-from-prod-using-vs-code)

Answer (score 3):

These commands:

- [sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass:MyApexClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_retrieve)
- [sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexClass:MyApexClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_deploy)

support the retrieve/deploy of individual components as well as sets of components identified in multiple ways.

Yes you need to have created an SFDX project to use them, but they do allow you to work on an individual file rather than having hundreds of files. Creating the SFDX project structure is just:

- [sfdx force:project:create -n mywork](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_project.htm)